# Trouble with custom drawing options with drawingManager in google maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-maps-api-3

So I am having trouble making custom marking options with as I am not able to give specific options the shape or color of icon I want to.

```
        customControlDiv.index = 1;
        var customControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var customControl = new CustomControl(customControlDiv, map,'red');
        var customControlDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
        var customControl1 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv1, map,'green');
        var customControlDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
        var customControl2 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv2, map,'teal');
        var customControlDiv3 = document.createElement('div');
        var customControl3 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv3, map,'black');
        var customControlDiv4 = document.createElement('div');
        var customControl4 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv4, map,'yellow');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv1);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv2);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv3);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv4);
        function CustomControl(controlDiv, map,flag) {

        // Set CSS for the control border
        var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
        controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
        controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        controlUI.style.borderWidth = '1px';
        controlUI.style.borderColor = '#ccc';
        controlUI.style.height = '25px';
        controlUI.style.width = '25px';
        controlUI.style.marginTop = '5px';
        controlUI.style.marginLeft = '-6px';
        controlUI.style.paddingTop = '1px';
        controlUI.style.cursor = 'flag';
        controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
        if (flag ==   'red')
            controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/RedFlag.JPG')";
        if (flag == 'green')
            controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/GreenFlag.JPG')";
        if (flag == 'teal')
            controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/TealFlag.JPG')";
        if (flag == 'black')
            controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/BlackFlag.JPG')";
        if (flag == 'yellow')
            controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/YellowFlag.JPG')";
        controlUI.style.backgroundSize = '20px';
        controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
        controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

        // Setup the click event listeners
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function () {
            var iconRed = {
                url: "/WebContent/Images/RedFlag.JPG", // url
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
            drawingManager.setOptions({
                drawingControl: true,
                icon : iconRed
            });
            drawingManager.setMap(map);
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

So this is snippet i having trouble here I am creating a div and adding it to drawing options.I did that successfully but every-time I click to add the marker the marker options defaults to the first one.Please refer to the image below.
[Map with custom drawing options][1].
So whenever I try to click any of the custom options which are indicated by flags as you can see in the image i want the marker to be a flag of that color but instead I am getting a marker of the flag of default marker which is white. Here is how I have set the default marker.
     var mapElement = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

```
        map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);

        var iconWhite = {
            url: "/WebContent/Images/WhiteFlag.JPG", // url
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
        };
        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,'marker']
            },
            markerOptions: {
                icon: iconWhite  
            },
            polygonOptions: {
                editable: true,
                draggable: true,
                strokecolor: '#E9967A'
            }
        });

        drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

i am sorry to give code that way just want to direct attention to the right place.The whole code is also attached.

```js
var map;
        var drawingManager;
        var shapes = [];

        function initMap() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51686166794058, 3.5945892333984375);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 7,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: false
            }
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });
            // Try HTML5 geolocation.
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var pos = {
                        lat: position.coords.latitude,
                        lng: position.coords.longitude
                    };

                    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                    infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
                    map.setCenter(pos);
                }, function() {
                    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                });
            } else {
                // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
                handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
        
            //Getting map DOM element
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

            map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
            
            var iconWhite = {
                url: "/WebContent/Images/WhiteFlag.JPG", // url
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            var iconRed = {
                url: "/WebContent/Images/RedFlag.JPG", // url
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };
            drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                    drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,'marker']
                },
                markerOptions: {
                    icon: iconWhite  
                },
                polygonOptions: {
                    editable: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    strokecolor: '#E9967A'
                }
            });

            drawingManager.setMap(map);
            var customControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var customControl = new CustomControl(customControlDiv, map,'red');
            var customControlDiv1 = document.createElement('div');
            var customControl1 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv1, map,'green');
            var customControlDiv2 = document.createElement('div');
            var customControl2 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv2, map,'teal');
            var customControlDiv3 = document.createElement('div');
            var customControl3 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv3, map,'black');
            var customControlDiv4 = document.createElement('div');
            var customControl4 = new CustomControl(customControlDiv4, map,'yellow');

            customControlDiv.index = 1;
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv1);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv2);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv3);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customControlDiv4);
            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
            map.addListener('bounds_changed', function () {
                searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
            });
            var markers = [];
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

                if (places.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                // Clear out the old markers.
                markers.forEach(function (marker) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                });
                markers = [];

                // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                places.forEach(function (place) {
                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                        return;
                    }
                    var icon = {
                        url: place.icon,
                        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };

                    // Create a marker for each place.
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon,
                        title: place.name,
                        position: place.geometry.location
                    }));

                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        // Only geocodes have viewport.
                        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                    }
                });
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            });
            // Add a listener for creating new shape event.
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function (event) {
                var newShape = event.overlay;
                newShape.type = event.type;
                shapes.push(newShape);
                if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode()) {
                    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
                }

            });

            // add a listener for the drawing mode change event, delete any existing polygons
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "drawingmode_changed", function () {
                if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode() != null && drawingManager.getDrawingMode() != 'marker') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                        shapes[i].setMap(null);
                    }
                    shapes = [];
                }
            });


            // Add a listener for the "drag" event.
            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, "overlaycomplete", function (event) {
                overlayDragListener(event.overlay);
                $('#vertices').val(event.overlay.getPath().getArray());
            });

        }

        function overlayDragListener(overlay) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(overlay.getPath(), 'set_at', function (event) {
                $('#vertices').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(overlay.getPath(), 'insert_at', function (event) {
                $('#vertices').val(overlay.getPath().getArray());
            });
        }
        
        function CustomControl(controlDiv, map,flag) {

            // Set CSS for the control border
            var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
            controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
            controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
            controlUI.style.borderWidth = '1px';
            controlUI.style.borderColor = '#ccc';
            controlUI.style.height = '25px';
            controlUI.style.width = '25px';
            controlUI.style.marginTop = '5px';
            controlUI.style.marginLeft = '-6px';
            controlUI.style.paddingTop = '1px';
            controlUI.style.cursor = 'flag';
            controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
            if (flag ==   'red')
                controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/RedFlag.JPG')";
            if (flag == 'green')
                controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/GreenFlag.JPG')";
            if (flag == 'teal')
                controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/TealFlag.JPG')";
            if (flag == 'black')
                controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/BlackFlag.JPG')";
            if (flag == 'yellow')
                controlUI.style.backgroundImage = "url('/WebContent/Images/YellowFlag.JPG')";
            controlUI.style.backgroundSize = '20px';
            controlUI.title = 'Click to set the map to Home';
            controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

            // Setup the click event listeners
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function () {
                var iconRed = {
                    url: "/WebContent/Images/RedFlag.JPG", // url
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 40), // scaled size
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                };
                drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
                drawingManager.setOptions({
                    drawingControl: true,
                    icon : iconRed
                });
                drawingManager.setMap(map);
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>  
<input id="pac-input" class="controls input-lg active" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" >
   <div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;position:relative">
       
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: anyone is welcome to edit the structure of my question.I would really appreciate the help..thanks..!!

Comment: People who have viewed it please do let me know if something is not clear I can explain..!!